# Telegram bot API: how to understand if there was an invite link?

Tags: telegram-bot

Is there an ability in Telegram bot API to understand if a user connected through an invite link?
I received an Update message but didn't find any information if the user joined through invite link or simply found the group and join.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do it for now :(

Comment: It is very sad :(